# Why is an un-required field required?

Tags: file-uploads, fields

I have a template with just two fields is it, an optional field for a thumbnail photograph and a body field for text. Only the body field is required. However, when I attempt to save an entry with just the body content entered I am unable to save the entry and I get a notice below the File field that says:

> You did not select a file to upload.

I have double checked the field several times and confirmed that it is not required. Has anyone else had this experience and better yet know how to resolve the problem? I am running ee 2.7.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer. It is a bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19732