# Channel form problem with file fleld flagged as required

Tags: matrix, file-uploads, channel-form, file-field

I've send the same question on Ellislab Forum but without answers...

I’m testing the new **channel form** and i’ve seen that if a *file field* is flagged as **required** field the form don’t pass the check.

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors
The xxxx field is required.
Return to Previous Page
```

The same problem also in a grid field or a matrix field that contain a column where file field is flagged as required field.

If I remove the flag (required field) all are ok.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Tested with:

- Expressionengine v2.7.2
- Matrix v2.5.8

This is the template:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="box" return="box/index" entry_id="{segment_3}" class="channel_form" include_assets="yes"}
    {field:box_photohead}
    {field:box_intructions}
    
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Comment: To ask the obvious, the problem is you get the error even when you've selected a file to upload? Is that right?

Comment: yes, I select a file and then push the submit button..

Comment: and is no errors in CP publish page? can you publish your template here?

Comment: no errors in CP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s accepted as Bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19837 and it will be Fixed in Upcoming Release.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to another bug regarding the file field.
[Why is an un-required field required?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/why-is-an-un-required-field-required)

That bug prevents an entry being posted if:

1. The upload directory is set to a specific directory
2. A specific file type (e.g. image) is specified.

Changing either of these conditions allow the entry to be submitted.

So I would suggest setting the upload directory to "Any" and the file type to "Any" and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've tested with the "Any" options but this don't resolve the problem. (Note: the File_field.php is updated because the installed version is 2.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

This is now also being addressed in an EE bug report. Check for the final answer there as it unfolds.

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19837

Comment: Now Accepted as BUG.
Waiting for solution.

Comment: Was this resolved for Matrix?

We have a matrix with a required file upload.

In the CMS all works fine, BUT in {exp:channel:form} uploads or submissions throw the error “column is required.”

This is EE v2.8.1 and Matrix 2.5.8.